# Lightbox Controller attempt to present

Tags: swift, lightbox

Attempt to present <Lightbox.LightboxController: 0x7f8862022600> on <UIViewController: 0x7f8865d2d630> whose view is not in the window hierarchy![enter image description here][1]

Please see attached attachment for more description...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTnvs.png

please help to resolve this error

call in UITableViewCell (preVC is main viewcontroller)

```
let controller = LightboxController(images: self.imgArrMain, startIndex: indexPath.row)
    controller.pageDelegate         = self
    controller.dismissalDelegate    = self
    controller.dynamicBackground    = true
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    preVC.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

Comment: provide some code, not image.

Comment: this error got when I Light box Controller use in table view cell

Comment: Does your table view reside on view controller? Or table view is a separate view instantiated from nib file? In the second case, you cannot present a controller from a view, you have to make it from the view controller, so (I can presume you're doing it) from didSelectItemAtIndexPath method use delegate to pass it to the view controller & then present it. Please let me know it helps.

Comment: @Zulqarnayn thanks for your help, replay & commit

I have fixed it by using parent view controller, I forgot that passing "preVC" value from view controller class.

pls upvote this question